# Normalize a periodic parameter

Tags: estimation, normalization, parameterization

I am using inverse modelling software ([PEST](http://www.pesthomepage.org/)) to estimate a periodic parameter for the direction of anisotropy, $\hat{\theta}$, which is somewhere in $[0^{\circ}, 180^{\circ})$ (i.e., has a wavelength of 180°). With PEST, parameters must be defined with lower/upper bounds and an initial guess. The inverse model will then seek to minimize the objective function by adjusting the parameter up/down within the bounds.

The problem is that my parameter is periodic, and this is difficult for inverse modelling software to solve. If the ideal $\theta$ is near 90°, then there isn't any issue solving for this parameter, since it is far from 0° or 180°, and it behaves somewhat linearly. However, if the ideal $\theta$ is near 0° or 180°, then the program will have difficulty approaching this answer to either the lower or upper bounds, since it does not understand periodicity.

Is there a technique to transform a periodic parameter, such that it behaves linear? I already have both pre- and post-processing routines in Python that can be adapted to transform this parameter.

Comment: What's the matter with just allowing $\theta$ to lie in $[0, 360]$?

Comment: @whuber if you consider the direction of horizontal anisotropy, and if the ideal direction is 0°, then there would be three local minima at 0°, 180° and 360°. Although with this range, there would be a better defined minima around 180°.

Comment: And doesn't that do the trick? A numeric solver will find one of the local minima and settle on it.  If you add a very tiny penalty to keep away from the boundary--and it's likely the software already does this internally--then when working correctly, the software will choose the middle minimum and therefore not (falsely) report a boundary solution.

Comment: Can you recast your bounds to [-90,90), leaving only one solution, not near a boundary?

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept mapping this one parameter into two, using

```
x1=cos( x/lambda )
x2=sin( x/lambda )
```

can be useful.